# Making data sent from a mobile phone client to a Java EE web app via web service wait for confirmation before being saved in a database

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee

What is the best approach for making data wait for administrator confirmation before saving it in a database in Java EE web application after getting it (the data) from an mobile phone client through a REST web service?

I think it's not a good idea to save the data in the application scope as it can use a lot of memory and it can take a lot of time for the administrator to confirm the storage of the data in the database which with a eventually huge amount of data can decrease the performance of the web app in the meanwhile.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table (T1) to hold the temporary data. Once your admin starts viewing, show him the data from this T1 table. Once approved, copy into your actual table, and once done, delete from T1 table.